# User Defined Functions in Excel and Speed Issues

Tags: excel, optimization, vba, user-defined-functions

I have an Excel model that uses almost all UDFs. There are say, 120 columns and over 400 rows. The calculations are done vertically and then horizontally --- that is first all the calculations for column 1 are done, then the final output of column 1 is the input of column 2, etc. In each column I call about six or seven UDFs which call other UDFs. The UDFs often output an array.

The inputs to each of the UDFs are a number of variables, some range variables, some doubles. The range variables are converted to arrays internally before their contents are accessed.

My problem is the following, I can build the Excel model without UDFs and when I run simulations, I can finish all computations in X hours. When I use UDFs, the simulation time is 3X hours or longer. (To answer the obvious question, yes, I need to work with UDFs because if I want to make small changes to the model (like say add another asset type (it is a financial model)) it takes nearly a day of remaking the model without UDFs to fit the new legal/financial structure, with UDFs it takes about 20 minutes to accommodate a different financial structure.)

In any case, I have turned off screen updating, there is no copying and pasting in the functions, the use of Variant types is minimal, all the data is contained in one sheet, i convert all range type variables to  arrays before getting the contents.

What else can I do other than getting a faster computer or the equivalent to make the VBA code/Excel file run faster? Please let me know if this needs more clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a function here? or a simplified version so we can have a look?

Comment: wow, i didn't think i'd get responses so quickly. i'll see if i can post a simplified version of what's going on some time during the week. thanks for the messages!

Comment: It sounds like you might be at the point where the programmer-overhead to code up your UDFs in C and package them in an XLL is worth it to save the execution-overhead from calling lots of VBA UDFs...

Answer (score 5):

There is a slowdown bug in the way Excel handles UDFs. Each time a UDF gets calculated Excel refreshes the VBE title bar (you can see it flicker). For large numbers of UDFs this is very slow.
The bypass is very simple in Manual Calculation mode: just initiate the calculation from VBA using something like Application.Calculate (you can trap F9 etc with OnKey).

see http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm for some more details.

Comment: +1 for the link, would be +1 for being the owner of the link!

Answer (score 4):

Couple of general tips.

1. Take your function and work out where the bottlenecks really are. See this question for the [use of timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190833/what-are-the-best-tools-for-optimizing-queries-in-vba-and-why) in excel. I'm sure there are VBA profilers out there... but you probably don't need to go that far. *(NB: do this with one cell of data first...)*
2. Think about your design... 400x120 cells of data is **not** a lot. And for it to take hours that must be painful. (*In the past i've cracked it after waiting a minute for 1,000s of `VLOOKUPS()` to return*) anyway maybe instead of having having a stack of UDFs why not have a simple subroutine that `for..each` through the range and does what you need it to do. 48,000 cells could take seconds or maybe just minutes. You could then associate the subroutine with a button or menu item for the user.

Out of interest i had a quick look at option 2 and created MyUDF(), using the sub `DoMyUDF()` to call it for the active selection worked 10x faster for me, than having the UDF in each and every cell.

```
Option Explicit



Function MyUDF(myVar As Variant) As Variant
  MyUDF = myVar * 10
End Function

Sub DoMyUDF()
  Dim r As Range
  Dim c As Variant

  Dim t As Single
  t = Timer


  If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
    Exit Sub
  End If


  Set r = Selection.Cells

  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

  For Each c In r
    c.Value = MyUDF(c.Value)

    Application.StatusBar = "DoMyUDF(): " & Format(Timer - t, "#0.0000ms")
  Next

  Debug.Print "DoMyUDF(): " & Format(Timer - t, "#0.0000ms")

End Sub
```

If you replace `MyUDF()` with your UDF this may only save you 4.5 minutes... but it's possible there are some other economies you can build in. Especially if you are repeating the same calcs over and over again.

Comment: interesting, i'll try this out. the problem is that while 120x400 cells of data is not a lot, i have to do 30,000+ simulations. in the past, i was able to do this within an hour (without UDFs), but right now it's taking 3 hours or so.

i will try your suggestions and see what happens. in the meanwhile, thanks for taking the time out to respond!

Comment: You can also make things a bit faster by loading a variant array to the usedrange of your worksheet, then populate that array with cell values, and put that variant array as the usedrange's value.  This is significantly faster than telling Excel to populate each individual cell with a value one at a time...

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered replacing the UDF (which gets called once per output cell) with a macro, which can operate on a range of cells in a loop?

UDF setup/teardown is very slow, and *anything* each UDF call does in common with other UDFs (reading from overlapping inputs, for example) becomes extra effort.

I've been able to improve performance 10-50x doing this--had a situation less than a month ago involving a spreadsheet with 4000-30000 UDF calls, replaced them with a single macro that operates on a few named ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Control and minimize recalculations with

```
wks.EnableCalculation = False
```

or

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Also, minimize the exchanges between VBA and the workbooks. It is faster to read and write a blocs of cells at once into an array

```
MyArray = range("B2:B20000")
```

rather than cell by cell (for each...).

Comment: ah yeah, should've mentioned, calculation was set to manual. unfortunately, the nature of the calculations requires that i cannot take the whole range in as an input in advance. it works like this, func1(A1:A5) outputs to A6:A10, then func2(A6:A10) outputs to A11:A15, etc.

Comment: you can also use Range("xxx").Calculate if required

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you start the recalc from the VBA and not from the spreadsheet, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730921.aspx#Office2007excelPerf_Overview
and the section about Faster VBA User-Defined Functions.
That is 
  Application.Calculate
is much faster (in my test case 100 times) than pressing F9 in the spreadsheet.