# Excel VBA function to lookup value in a Cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I know how to do this in excel using match and index.  My spreadsheet has a lot of these lookups though and it has to be easily auditable.

In pure excel formulas it is a simple:

```
=index(match()...match()) of the table
```

although easy to do it created big headackes if the size of the table changes,etc.   the readability of the formula is also bad.   Named ranges for the table and the headers and columns make it even more difficult to troubleshoot.

```
      Col1  Col2    Col3
Row1    1   2   3
Row2    4   5   6
Row3    7   8   9
```

I am naming this range with the row and column names as first row and column respectively.

so the Excel variable will be called test_table.

want to write a VBA function that i can call with:

```
=VBAlookup("Row2", "Col2", test_table)
returns 5
```

at moment i am using python with DataNitro and pandas to easily do this splicing.  Not good at VBA so writing this in VBA going to take quite a while.  Sure that I am not the first or only to look for this functionality, but google search does not seem to get me anywhere.

Don't want to answer my own question, but my solution so far (adapted from @John Bustos' answer below) is:

```
Public Function VBAlookup(RowName As Variant, ColName As Variant, Table As Range) As Variant

Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim ColNum As Integer

    VBAlookup = "Not Found"

    For RowNum = 1 To Table.Rows.Count
        If Table.Cells(RowNum, 1) = RowName Then
            For ColNum = 1 To Table.Columns.Count
                If Table.Cells(1, ColNum) = ColName Then
                    VBAlookup = Table.Cells(RowNum, ColNum)
                End If
            Next ColNum
        End If
    Next RowNum

End Function
```

This gets any type of content in correct format and also gives some feedback if value is not in the table

Comment: So, just to understand, your table will actually have the row and column headers AND the ranges will be named vertically and horizontally or just one or the other? And, if so, which one??

Comment: want to pass just the whole table.   By definition the Names will be in 1st row and column.  otherwise you have to name three things from within excel.  Think i managed to something like this a while bqack in VBA.  basically parses of 1st row and column from the passed table.   do an index lookup in each and then return the intersection of those from the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Public Function VBAlookup(RowName As String, ColName As String, Table As Range) As String

Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim ColNum As Integer

    VBAlookup = ""

    For RowNum = 1 To Table.Rows.Count
        If Table.Cells(RowNum, 1).Text = RowName Then
            For ColNum = 1 To Table.Columns.Count
                If Table.Cells(1, ColNum).Text = ColName Then
                    VBAlookup = Table.Cells(RowNum, ColNum).Text
                End If
            Next ColNum
        End If
    Next RowNum

End Function
```

**Note that I did not put in any error checking, etc, which would be good practice!**

Comment: works great.  The information in the table could be values, dates or text.   AS currently written the function returns the value as text.   Have tried to define the function as returning a object and also changing the line returning the value to do it as an object.  Trying to debug myself.  Maybe you have a quick suggestion?

Comment: changed to as variant at function def line and removed the .text from return line

Comment: Function does not scale very well... am calling it from 10 different cells now with small (10x4 table).   Seems that excels recalc goes multiple times through spreadsheet. so the function gets called exponentially!!!

Comment: I can see how this could happen and that would !!SUCK!! - Without knowing your exact situation, I'd say one possible solution to speed things up is to, for example, change the spreadsheet to include a macro called, say, "Calculate_My_UDF" that calculates your VBALookup cells and simply puts in the calculated value rather than leaving it as a volatile function (you can maybe mark those cells with having the formula in the cell comment, for example)... That has the advantage of speeding up your spreadsheet, but you lose the dynamic calculations... Just a possible thought....

Comment: Maybe look online too - I found this topic which discusses some solutions, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1291605/1693085 - Either way, let me know....

Comment: great thanks. Will check.   Seems that it was not this code that caused the big slowdown.   I also had some data tabels in the spreadsheet.  I switched of auto calculation on those and it seemed to solve most of the speed issue.   Going to have many more of these though so I will still try to optimize.

Comment: I was wondering about that - This code is truly fairly efficient - It's nothing more than 2 for loops that scan one row and one column... That **SHOULDN'T** (doesn't mean wouldn't, though :) ) slow things down too much... Either way, glad you found ways to speed it up....